# Gridview multiple header rows in c#

Tags: gridview, header

How to show multirow header in gridview in asp.net ?

I need use header template and item template and design it according to my requirements

I have tried the code below but I don't understand because the columns are not aligned.

The output is :

[image]

Please can you help me ?

Thanks in advance for nay help.

My code below

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="mGrid"
        HorizontalAlign="Center"
        Width="100"
        DataKeyNames="sID">
        <Columns>


            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgOrdersShow"
                        runat="server" OnClick="Show_Hide_OrdersGrid"
                        ImageUrl="/aspnet/img/plus.png"
                        CommandArgument="Show" />                
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>



            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <th colspan="6">Category</th>
                    <tr class="gvHeader">
                        <th style="width: 0px"></th>
                        <th colspan="3">Hardware</th>
                        <th colspan="3">Software</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="gvHeader">
                        <th></th>
                        <th>S. No.</th>

                    </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <td>test1</td>
                    <td>test2</td>
                    <td>test3</td>
                    <td>test4</td>
                    <td>test5</td>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        CssClass="mGrid"
        HorizontalAlign="Center"
        DataKeyNames="sID">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgOrdersShow"
                        runat="server" 
                        OnClick="Show_Hide_OrdersGrid"
                        ImageUrl="/aspnet/img/plus.png"
                        CommandArgument="Show" />                
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" 
                            runat="server"
                            Text="S. No."
                            ToolTip="S. No.">
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="18">Category</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="2">Hardware</th>
                                <th colspan="2">Software</th>
                                <th colspan="2">Hardware1</th>
                                <th colspan="2">Software1</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>test1</td>
                                <td>test2</td>
                                <td>test3</td>
                                <td>test4</td>
                                <td>test5</td>
                                <td>test6</td>
                                <td>test7</td>
                                <td>test8</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>your value</td>
                                <td>your value</td>
                                <td>your value</td>
                                <td>your value</td>
                                <td>your value</td>
                                <td>your value</td>
                                <td>your value</td>
                                <td>your value</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```